# How to redirect a Heroku domain to a custom domain?

Tags: domains, 301-redirect, heroku

Let's say my web can be accessed with `www.example.com` and `example.herokuapp.com`.

How can I redirect `example.herokuapp.com/*` to `www.example.com/*`?

[Heroku suggests that I use HTTP status 301 Moved Permanently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) but doesn’t explain on how to do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469742/how-to-implement-301-redirects-with-django-heroku - Answered here.

Comment: @Yhorian So I guess the answer is you can't do it on Heroku but you have to do within your own apps?

Comment: A 301 redirect is a HTTP header. It can be set by the server or the app. You've chosen to outsource the server architecture to Heroku. You only have one choice.

Answer (score 1):

A 301 Moved Permanently is a HTTP header sent from the server to the browser instructing the browser to redirect the user to the correct domain name, while at the same time telling search engines where the correct address is.

The way I have achieved this is to add logic to my Heroku app's to ensure the correct FQDN is being used. If it is using the `herokuapp.com` address then the 301 header is sent with the correct URI to go to (including URL path and query strings to ensure a seamless experience for the end user). The trick here is to make sure that if the user requests the URL `appp1.herokuapps.com/folder1/page.html` then they are 301 redirected to `www.domain.com/folder1/page.html` and not `www.domain.com` otherwise it can throw the entire user experience off as users expecting a particular page are instead being redirected to your homepage just because of the URL redirection needed.